# run two animations at the same time iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I know the basics about iPhone sdk. I am building an app which is basically like a power point presentation; therefore, I know how to create basic animations such as moving an image from point a to point b etc. I will like to create animations that go more in like a circular path. I was thinking that if I created an animation dealing with the x component of an object an another animation dealing with the y component of the same object I could create an animation that moves more like a parabola if both animations are run at the same time. So in short I am just trying to improve my animations and I just know the basics of objective-c. I am looking forward to read tutorials that you recommend. Also a simple example moving something in a non-linear path will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to grab one of the available game engines to create your presentation-ware. They usually have some built in support for parabolic motion.

Comment: I could probably use unity but I have to distribute it and I don't think the company wants to purchase a license for that. If there is software that is free and also that enables me to distribute it then I will be interested.

Comment: Have a look at [Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/).  It handles what you are looking for, and is free.